# Has anyone had their iOS App rejected by Apple for using the devices UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios, deprecated, udid

I have heard some rumours that Apple is rejecting apps for using the iOS5 deprecated method `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]`. Can anyone confirm that they have had their App rejected for this reason? I know of the alternatives to using this deprecated method, but one of our customers is requesting we use a 3rd party library that we know uses this method.

I would be surprised if this is the case as the API method has been deprecated and not made private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple is not rejecting apps because of this. I collect device UDIDs along with tokens within my apps that support push notifications and they have all been approved. UDIDs are simply **deprecated**, meaning that Apple will eventually not allow you to access them. Everything still works and will be approved.

I heard that Apple deprecated access to UDIDs to prevent developers and third party analysts from being able to identify specific people. If it truly was because of issues with iCloud, Apple would clearly have fixed this instead of inconveniencing everyone else.

**Edit:** It looks like Apple is rejecting *some* apps for accessing the device's UDID. Just to be safe, I would use `CFUUID` to create a random unique identifier. You can use `NSUserDefaults` or the keychain to save it. The advantage to the keychain is that if the user deletes your app, the keychain items are not deleted so you can still access the UDID if the user reinstalls your app. It will only get deleted if the user restores their device.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  Have these apps been submitted after the deprecating of the method?

Comment: Yes. UDID access was deprecated in iOS 5.0 and apps have been submitted since then.

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't think that Apple would start rejecting the use of an iOS5 deprecated method.

Comment: Nah. That would be pretty bad for a lot of people at the moment. I think the alternative that people are turning to is the device's MAC address (though you run into the problem of spoofed addresses on jailbroken devices...)

Comment: READ THIS: I just read that Apple is starting to reject apps submitted now that access the UDID. Any apps you have on the App Store that do this should be fine, but any newly submitted app may be rejected!

Comment: I don't know if there is any significance, but my appDidFinishLaunching has a call to it, and just got approved yesterday.  (My lawyer would have me add, your results may vary.)

Answer (score 3):

> Using Identifiers in Your Apps
>
> Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6. You can find more details in the [UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html).

Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/

Answer (score 2):

It appears that App Review is enforcing this rule on apps that *transmit* the UDID without getting the user's permission -- as suggested by [this post](http://www.imore.com/2012/03/30/apple-is-now-rejecting-apps-that-collect-udid-without-permission/) -- rather than ones that simply invoke the deprecated API.

We had an update in review for an app that would send the device UDID to our server, on which we would use it to index the user's account. We decided not to take any chances and change our code to generate an app-specific unique identifier, as proposed by [documentation on the deprecation of the UDID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier)

Answer (score 1):

now Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
```

and must to add ADSupport framework

Answer (score 1):

Since May 1, Apple is rejecting all apps which access to the UDID.
But it seems the only thing that they can do is to check if the string "uniqueIdentifier" is in the binary or not.

So even if you don't acces anymore to the uniqueIdentifier of the phone, but you give to one variable the same name, they will find it in the binary and they will reject it cause they can't do the difference.

If you want to know if you binary contain it, you can change the extension of the .ipa (export for ad-hoc deployment) to .zip, unzip it, and do `fgrep -R uniqueIdentifier .` in the terminal at the payload/ folder.
You can also do this command in your project folder to find the files which contain the string.

This worked for me.