# UDID - does Apple began to reject?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, udid

We are about to post an app that use UDID. We plan to remove this access due to the mess that Apple does around this identifier access. But we plan it for the next release.

Because I'm afraid of failing my review, I would know your experience :

Have you post an application these last weeks that use UDID? Does Apple began to reject that kind of apps?

Comment: Why take chance..? If Apple has deprecated 'uniqueIdentifier', then use CFUUID (suggested by Apple itself) & chillax..!!

Comment: That's not the subject of the thread, I know CFUUID exists and we are about to implement that kind of solution in next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]

Just saw this http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/

---

In my humble opinion you should implement your own method for generating a UDID now. It is not that hard and there are plenty of good references around the web.

Thing about how much more work it will be required once UDID is removed from the SDK and you need to work out a migration strategy for your existing users. Definitely not worth the trouble.

In saying all that, I doubt your app will be rejected for using a deprecated method.

Here is a similar SO question in case you're interested [Has anyone had their iOS App rejected by Apple for using the devices UDID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459188/has-anyone-had-their-ios-app-rejected-by-apple-for-using-the-devices-udid)

Comment: Thanks for the first link. Your second one is a bit old: things have changed. Of course, we plan to generate our unique app ID, but its for the _next_ release.

Answer (score 2):

My app approved on 4/10 using UDID. So it's not 100% rejection yet.

Answer (score 1):

Vignesh's link to Oliver's post which thinks that only apps that send the UDID via HTTP are being rejected.  The following [post](http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/?utm_source=pulsenews&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Techcrunch%20%28TechCrunch%29) indicates that if the app asks the user first before transmitting the UDID via HTTP, then the app will not be rejected.

Maybe asking the user before transmitting the UDID via HTTP is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Identifiers in Your Apps
>
> Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6. You can find more details in the [UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html).

Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/

(copied from my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306133/1710611))